# Service Access on Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi is there a best practice to access google cloud services such as bigtable and pubsub when running services inside kubernetes? Or should I just place the json credentials available for each pod during deployment?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

When creating your cluster (or node pool) you can set the scopes (which are permissions) that will be applied to each of the VMs. For example, to [allow access to pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/configure), you could set either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` (the second one has much broader permissions so if you only want pubsub you should use the first to stick to the principle of least privilege).